Duplicate class in Kotlin in Android
Image Example
I kept on getting an error that there is a duplicate error in classes.
I've tried deleting the files from the org.jetbrains.kotlin, but whenever I build the app in Android Studio, the files will be redownloaded again.
This is my module app Gradle code:
Here is the error code
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)


Does this answer your question? Duplicate class in Kotlin Android

If you are building android project using java, here is solution for you.
Step1: project level build.gradle
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    }

Step2: Application level build.gradle
dependencies {

.....

  constraints{
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.10'
    }
}

Now your error is solved 100%
